# JavaScript для сканирования

Tags: javascript

Возможно реализовать в html ссылку с JavaScript'ом, которая будет открывать программу сканирования документов и присваивать имя файла этой ссылки?

Answer (score 3):

Нет, у вас нету доступа к программам из javascript.

Причина этому — ваша же безопасность: представьте себе, что было бы, если бы какой-нибудь сайт запустил на вашем компьютере `echo Y | format C:`?